# Need a reference book for stokes theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am studying singular homology, I would like a good reference for the proof of stokes theorem for chains in manifolds.

Thank you!

Comment: Off the top of  my head, I would try Spivak's "Calculus on manifolds" or Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis."

Comment: Vector Analysis by Janich